# Change Friendly Name on Windows 7 Lock Screen

Tags: windows-7, login-screen, username, ctrl-alt-delete

I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Service Pack 1 and log into a domain.  If I lock my work laptop, it shows the following...

> Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to unlock this computer.
>
> First M.. Last (DOMAIN\username) is logged on.

Notice that there are 2 periods `..` after the middle initial `M`.  **How do I correct this?**

I searched through the registry and found one or more places where the data was "First M.. Last".  I changed this to be "First M. Last" and rebooted.  This didn't work.  I then changed this to be "First Last" and rebooted.  This didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a domain user the name needs to be updated at the domain level, not the computer level.

A domain admin will need to open up 'AD Users and Computers' and fix your middle initial (ie: remove the period).

Answer (score 1):

Given from the information given, it looks like you are a domain user.

Your username and displayname are set through the Active Directory and upon each login it will get the information from the server. Changing it locally therefor is pointless.

You need to ask someone that can make the change on the serverside to change your name. It is very easy, but you need to do this from the active directory.